# Checksum to Identify Solutions of N-Queen

Tags: recursion, dictionary, checksum, backtracking

I have solved the N-Queen problem by using a backtracking algorithm and can generate all unique and distinct solutions in C#. Although, I have restricted the level of recursion by finding valid positions in every row, the algorithm would be hopelessly slow for N > 15. I suspect the reason is for every new solution I have to generate all 8 symmetrical counterparts and check this versus already found solutions. If none of these are already included the new solution can be added to the unique solutions.

I saw somewhere a hint on attaching a checksum to each solution and create a dictionary of with  where the checksum would be the key and solution is a List. I can't find the article and otherwise is very new to the concept of checksum.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hash or checksum generation for N-queens? A few points:

1. Queens are equivalent to each other. This means we don't want to successively multiply the Queen terms of the checksum to distinguish them, as they should be equivalent.
2. Position is what's important.

So we could start with something like:

```
public int hashSolution (Queen[] queens) {
    int h = 0;
    for (Queen q : queens) {
        int queenHash = (q.getX() * 23) + q.getY();     // 23 is a prime.
        h += queenHash;
    }
    return h;
}
```